# Setting up replication alerts

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, replication, alerts

I 'm trying to configure alerts for replication. Currently on my test setup I run everything under user 'sa'. When I try to set up alert for agent failure I get the following error

**Login failed for user 'sa'.**

This error is shown when i try to add a new operator.

Any suggestions how to fix this problem.
thanks

Comment: Have you tried a different user with sysadmin role?

Comment: @HaniElMouallem please ask for clarification using comments, not answers.